Python Error: 'Term is not recognized as cmdlet, function, script file or operable program' when running code with Shift+Enter
So I have a longer file where I took a lot of notes in comments and wrote down examples from class. Instead of running the whole file whenever I want to try some lines of code, I would like to only run a selected section of the code. Whether I use Shift+Enter or Right-click > Run selection I keep running into the same error.
When I run the whole code, there is no problem. I'm on Windows 10.
This is the error I get:
The term 'x' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
Here is a screenshot:
Error when running a section of Python code with Shift+Enter
Can anyone help?
I have also re-installed both Python and Visual Studio a few times, as well as the extensions within Visual Studio for Python. The error remains the same.

It appears you have exited the python interpreter in the terminal window that vs-code is using to run the lines.
I was able to replicate this by creating a new python file in vs-code with the following contents
x = 2
print(x)

Make sure all integrated terminals are closed, then highlight and run the code and via Right-click > Run Python > Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal.
Vs-code will then open a new terminal running the python interpreter and run the selected lines.
Now do Ctrl-Z+Enter in the interpreter window, and rerun the selected lines.
To fix this, just close any open Python integrated terminal windows. Make sure to use the trashcan icon and not the "x" as that will minimize the terminal instead of closing it.
